# Widget click not working after changing device language

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

I have simple widget with 2 TextView, in it's onUpdate():

```
 PendingIntent pendingIntent =  IntentUtils.getClockWidgetProviderPendingIntent(context);
 views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.timeText, pendingIntent);
```

Works great, but when users changes the device language they can't click on widget anymore (untill rebooting device).

Any ideas what is the problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using updateAppWidget invocations somewhere else in the code?
You should always invoke `setOnClickPendingIntent` before each `updateAppWidget` invocation or you can use `public void partiallyUpdateAppWidget (int appWidgetId, RemoteViews views)` instead because

*"Note that because these updates are not cached, any state that they modify that is not restored by restoreInstanceState will not persist in the case that the widgets are restored using the cached version in AppWidgetService."*

So every time when user rotate device or change a language, the widget will be reseted to values that were keeped in latest updateAppWidget invocation.